# What did Nebula do in Avengers: Endgame?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Did the younger Nebula shoot and kill the older in *Avengers: Endgame* or was it the other way around? 
and
Was the shot fatal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a grandfather paradox in Endgame?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99656/is-there-a-grandfather-paradox-in-endgame) older Nebula killed her past self, and the paradox thing is addressed in the proposed dupe-target